# What fugacity actually is, and how it plays an important role on Bose gas?

Tags: chemical-potential, quantum-statistics

We know that the average occupation number cannot be negative for all systems and chemical potential must be negative in ideal Bose gas. This fact leads us to arrive a conclusion for fugacity which is related by chemical potential, as I quoted below from Greiner, Neise, Stocker, "*Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics*":

> The restriction of the fugacity to the interval $0 \leq z \leq 1$ is very important in the following. For a large volume, the sum over all one-particle states can be rewritten in terms of integral.

How can *negative chemical potential* help us to convert the sum to the integral for a large volume? As what can I think fugacity in an ideal Bose gas?